# How do I add an additional print statement for every print statement called in my code? (preferably using code decorators)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-decorators

I want to check if a print statement is being called and add an additional print statement after it, without having to add an empty print statement manually after every instance.
My output is currently like this:

```
Hello  
Hello  
Hello  
Hello

*(outputs this 10 times)*
```

while I would like it to look like this:

```
Hello

Hello

Hello

Hello

*(output 10 times as well in this pattern)*
```

I preferably want to use decorators as that is the easiest and best-looking solution, but another solution would also be okay!

I tried asking ChatGPT, but it doesn't change anything about the output.

Currently, this is my code:

```
def readability(func):
  def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    if callable(func) and func.__name__ == 'print':
      print(' ')
    return result
  return wrapper

@readability
def printing():
  j=10
  while j>0:
    print('hello')
    j-=1

printing()
```

Comment: why not just use `print('hello\n\n' * 10)`

Comment: I want to be able to apply it to other functions using print statements as well, hello is just sample text, the actual text would be longer and differ from line to line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original answer:

```py
original_print = print
def print(*args):
    original_print(*args)
    original_print('  ')

print('Hello')
```

Improved answer using `__builtins__`:

```py
def print(*args):
    __builtins__.print(*args)
    __builtins__.print('  ')
```

Both version produce the following output:

```
Hello
<blank line>
```

Comment: This worked for me and did exactly as I wanted, thanks! Only problem was that it crashed my entire collab file and I had to create a new file every time I tried to run it again, but i fixed it by running it once and then deleting it again.

Comment: @Acion I don't understand your comment but it does not sound good. Is there anything I could add to improve my answer?

Comment: This does nothing that `print(txt, end = ' \n\n')` does not do. It really is not a good idea to have a function which recursively calls a builtin function or which over-rides a built-in function name for no purpose.

Comment: @user19077881 it may not be the best of ideas. Please elaborate your objections to it. However, it solves a problem so this is not "for no purpose". There's also no recursive call involved as you state. You do seem to have a better solution, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [contextlib.ContextDecorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ContextDecorator) to be able to use either a decorator or a context manager, which lets you control more finely where you want to use your modified `print` function.

In order to replace `print`, you just have to use `print = your_own_function`. You can still access the original  `print` as `__builtins__.print`.

So, an example could be, with two sample personalized print functions which you can apply wherever you want: to a whole function using a decorator, or to a piece of code using a context manager:

```
from contextlib import ContextDecorator


def double_print(data):
    __builtins__.print(data)
    __builtins__.print()
    
def underlined_print(data):
    __builtins__.print(data)
    __builtins__.print('-'*len(str(data)))
    

class my_print_context(ContextDecorator):
    def __init__(self, print_function):
        self.print = print_function
    
    def __enter__(self):
        global print
        print = self.print
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        global print
        print = __builtins__.print
        return False
    
    
def nums():
    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
```

We can use this like this:

```
@my_print_context(double_print)
def nums2():
    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
     
        
print('\nNormal')        
nums()

print('\nDecorated')
nums2()

print('\nWith context manager')
with my_print_context(underlined_print):
    print('Hello')
    print('We are underlined')
    nums()

print('\nAfter the context')
nums()
```

which outputs:

```
Normal
0
1
2

Decorated
0

1

2


With context manager
Hello
-----
We are underlined
-----------------
0
-
1
-
2
-

After the context
0
1
2
```

Comment: Upvoted, for use of `__builtins__` if for nothing else. I knew it existed but could not recall and not find it either when I wrote my answer. This is much better than mine.